# How to bind object in different project maui c#

Tags: c#, binding, maui

Does anyone know how to bind an object to a different project ?

For example I have 2 projects. One is My maui app that contains the Mainpage.xaml and the other one is a dll that I would like to reuse potentially.

Let's say that the dll display a simple list with some customizations.

In my Maui app I would like to call the dll (the xaml view) and bind it the list I have created in order to display it.

i have made an example here :

https://github.com/VincentS90/TestBindingProperty.git

The listItems is instantiated and filled up somewhere else.
How could I "transfer" this ListItems properly to be used in the dll ?

For now, when executing nothing appears. I don't know if it is a syntax or concept problem.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/ways-create-netmaui-controls#3-using-contentview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your repo, you're making a custom view in one project and you want to consume that view in a second project that holds a reference to it. First, let's look at an example class that will consume the custom view:

```
namespace net_maui_list_consumer
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            BindingContext = new MainPageModel();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    class MainPageModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Object> Fruits { get; } = new ObservableCollection<object>
        {
            new Fruit{ Name = "Apple", Color = Colors.Red },
            new Fruit{ Name = "Orange", Color = Colors.Orange },
            new Fruit{ Name = "Banana", Color = Color.FromRgb(255, 204, 0) },
        };
    }
    class Fruit
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Color Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And we want to use our external `DisplayList` component to display it in some customized way:

[image: imported custom list view]

---

So in a project we'll call `IVSoftware.Maui.Demo.Components`, the custom view might be defined like this:

**CS**

```
namespace IVSoftware.Maui.Demo.Components;

public partial class DisplayList : ListView
{
    public DisplayList() => InitializeComponent();
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ListView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="IVSoftware.Maui.Demo.Components.DisplayList">
    
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame 
                            HeightRequest="80"
                            CornerRadius="20"
                            BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}">
                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                TextColor="White" 
                                FontSize="Small"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

---

And the "trick" to using the `DisplayList` from the external project is to qualify the assembly in the `xmlns` as shown here:

**Xaml in the main project**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ivs="clr-namespace:IVSoftware.Maui.Demo.Components;assembly=IVSoftware.Maui.Demo.Components"
             x:Class="net_maui_list_consumer.MainPage">

    <Grid>
        <ivs:DisplayList
            ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}"
            RowHeight="80"
        />
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/net-maui-list-consumer.git)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I understood better

Answer (score 0):

That's the issue with Bindings. You could make some changes and it will work.

Let's take a look at **ListDisplay** ContentView,

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:node="clr-namespace:ListBase"
             x:Class="ListBase.ListDisplay"
             x:Name="this">

    <ContentView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate
            x:DataType="node:NodeVM"
            x:Key="NodeTemplate">
            <!--Don't forget to add ViewCell tag-->
            <ViewCell>
                <VerticalStackLayout >

                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentView.Resources>

    <ListView
        ItemsSource="{Binding SourceItems,Source={x:Reference this}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}" />

</ContentView>
```

Several changes have been made comparing to yours,

**First,** In the `<DataTemplate>`, you should add a `<ViewCell>` tag. Otherwise it will throw an error. For more info, you could refer to [Populate a ListView with data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview#populate-a-listview-with-data).

**Second,** You should use `ItemsSource` and `ItemTemplate` Property for ListView instead of `BindableLayout.ItemsSource`. (I don't know why you use that) For more info, you could refer to [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview).

**Third,** You binds the `ItemsSource` Property to the `SourceItems` BindableProperty. You'd better use x:reference binding expressions,

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SourceItems,Source={x:Reference this}}"
```

'this' is the name I set for the ContentView. For more info, you may refer to [Create a ContentView-derived class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/contentview#create-a-contentview-derived-class)

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         ...
         x:Name="this">
```

Now you could customize the ListView in **TestBindingproperty**.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about this x:Reference :)

Comment: Just use my code and everything works fine. If you have any question, free to ask me:)